# After which event is safe to call ScrollIntoView on ListView?

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I need to restore the state after the back button is pressed. I'm currently doing this:

```
<ListView Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" />

private async void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await Task.Delay(100);
    listView.ScrollIntoView(myItem);
}
```

When I skip *Task.Delay* the *ScrollIntoView* call is ignored because the placeholder for *myItem* is not initialized yet.

Which *ListView* event I need to subscribe to instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why not call this inside `OnNavigatedTo` function of page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
       listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.Items[0]);
 }
```

Comment: This is not working because `OnNavigatedTo` is fired before the `listView` is fully initialized even though the `DataContext` is assigned in the constructor.

Comment: This works if you want to reset the listview to the first item, since the state of listview is maintained by default when you navigate back to that page. If you have set `NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required;`

Comment: I'm not experiencing this behavior. May be `CollectionViewSource` affecting this. I'm using it for grouping.

Comment: K that might be the issue. Since caching a page keeps its state maintained after navigation. I had to add the above code to return the listview to top element. If you want to scroll to particular element then you can do that after your code binding to your listview